# build a Qgis Modeler using raster calculator and integer values

Tags: python, qgis

I am trying to build a Modeler in Q GIS, and need to use variable strings in the raster calculator algorithm. In the screen shot N°2: i must use "a" and "b" constants in the expression, but I don't see how to find them?
Any help!, thanks.

[image]